# Button-Color based on className in scss

Tags: css, sass

Is there a neat, simple and beautiful way to implement something like this in scss:

```
&.red{
    --color:red;
}
&.green{
    --color:green;
}
&.blue{
    --color:blue;
}
&.yellow{
    --color:yellow;
} 
[...]
background-color:var(--color);
```

i was thinking something like this:

```
&.$color{
   --color:$color
}
```

im really new into scss and wanted to know if this is possible in some way.

Comment: I think you can make class like `red`, `green`, `yellow`, and add class in your code like `<button class = "mybtn red">Click Me</button>`.

Comment: @SatoTakeru yeah im doing this but in my scss i need to say to every different color something like "&.red{--color:red}" is there an easy way to do it for every color?

Comment: Do you mean `:root {--red: red}` and `background-color: var(--red)`?

Comment: kinda-ish, i mean that would be a not so nice way of writing it in my opinion. It would be easier to just write :root.classname{--color: classname} or something like that and later use this color as some type of variable in scss

Comment: I don't exactly understand what you want. Then, do you mean `$red: red;` and `background-color: $red`?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to loop through a list of colors to generate new classes, which is definitely doable with proper [interpolation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/interpolation):

```
.button {
  $colors: red, green, blue, yellow; // create a list of colors
  @each $color in $colors { // loop through each value of a list
    &.#{$color} { // need interpolation to use a sass variable in a css selector
      --color: #{$color}; // need interpolation for css variable assignment
      color: $color; // do not need interpolation for other css properties.
    }
  }
}
```

That will output the following compound selectors, based on the `$colors` list.

```css
.button.red {
  --color: red;
  color: red;
}
.button.green {
  --color: green;
  color: green;
}
.button.blue {
  --color: blue;
  color: blue;
}
.button.yellow {
  --color: yellow;
  color: yellow;
}
```

However, since you're already generating classes from a list, I'd suggest creating new class names rather than compound selectors, since these increase [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). By changing `&.#{$color}` to `&--#{$color}` in the loop above, you can get the following BEM-style classes:

```css
.button--red {
  --color: red;
  color: red;
}
.button--green {
  --color: green;
  color: green;
}

/* etc. */
```